# chrome goes back 2 times instead of one time when using history.pushState/location.hash

Tags: html, history.js, html5-history

1. open a new tab in Chrome (opens http://google.com for example)
2. open a `testpage.htm` containing `history.pushState({},"test","#lightbox");`
   which changes the url to `testpage.htm#lightbox`
3. if you hit the back button of your chrome the url is changed to `http://google.com`, which is two states back, not one

firefox and msie10 work both good, so it's a chrome issue
how can i fix this? is there a workaround?

thank you in advance

(feel free to give my question a better title and feel free to correct my english)

---

notes:

on step 2 you can also use `window.location.hash = "#lightbox"` but does the same issue

on step 3 you can simulate the back button from within your code, using `history.back()` and in this very case the url is switched to the correct one `testpage.htm`, so this is related only to the back button of Chrome's gui

I also tried

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", function(ev){ ev.preventDefault(); });
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function(ev){ ev.preventDefault(); });
```

without success :(

---

Update 2: does the same using [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js)

Comment: Sounds more like a bug in Chrome?

Comment: or webkit, because it does the same on android 2 and 4... don't know safari, but i guess the same

Comment: Question, does the content of the page reflect google.com, or is it just the address state that is wrong?

Comment: I was thinking that you maybe came across this bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=80697